# How to pass a reference to aframe component?

Tags: javascript, components, aframe

I'm writing a custom aframe component to render a mesh based on a very long array of objects.

Aframe documentation only lists array as an input type where you can pass an attribute and it will be parsed into an array `attributename="1 2 3"`

I would like to pass a javascript reference into the component from the outside with something like this:

```
const hugeArray = [{somejson}, ...]
const element = document.createElement('my-component');
element.<something happens here>
```

or create a component outside of DOM API and pass arguments to component's `init` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setAttribute`, which can take objects and arrays as well. Go through the `schema` rather than calling a method since the `init` handler will automatically get called for you at the right time.

https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/core/entity.html#setattribute-attr-value-componentattrvalue

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('mycomponent', {
  schema: { 
    yourData: {type: 'array'}
  },

  init: function () {
    console.log(this.data.yourData);
  }
});

const hugeArray = [{somejson}, ...]
const element = document.createElement('a-entity');
element.setAttribute('mycomponent', {yourData: hugeArray});
scene.appendChild(element);
```

Comment: Agreed, this is a much cleaner option.

Answer (score 2):

Found one way to do it.

```
const hugeArray = [{somejson}, ...]
const element = document.createElement('a-entity');
element.setAttribute('mycomponent', '');
//... add component to DOM and let it initialize
element.components.mycomponent.customMethod(hugeArray);
```

All that is assuming component is registered under a name "mycomponent" and has a method `customMethod` alongside init etc.